# Cannot changing login button color, have tried theme, plugins... is it GoDaddy managed?

Tags: themes, buttons

I have added this code into my theme Customization and also Simple Custom CSS plugin

```
.wp-core-ui #login .button-primary {
  background: #7e0001 !important; 
  background-image: none !important;
  border-color: #7e0001; 
}
```

For the life of me I cannot that code override the 'default blue' of the WordPress login button.  The only plugin that works is "Login Press" which seems to use the exact same CSS as me, but somehow WordPress pays attention to it and not my theme CSS.  I don't need to style the whole thing I just want to colorize the damn button.

Is it me?  Is it GoDaddy WordPress Managed hosting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The login page doesn't load your theme's stylesheet.

If you want to include extra CSS on your login page then you should hook [login_enqueue_scripts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/login_enqueue_scripts/) and write out an extra `<style>` tag there, or include another CSS file (or even your theme's full CSS file if you want to).

You could also use [login_head](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/login_head/), and there's an example of including another CSS file in the login_head documentation, but it sounds like login_enqueue_scripts is more correct.

Comment: Thank you.  I didn't realized the login page ignored custom CSS.  My solution rather than customize my theme was find a plugin that uses login_enqueue_scripts and has an option to add custom css.  There are lots of solutions, but most of them are too heavy handed and do too much.  The unfortunately named "BM Custom Login" allows for a custom logo and color, and some extra CSS.  It took some tweaking but it works.  Thanks